# Svelte, TypeScript, Bootstrap and custom events with dots in their name

Tags: typescript, twitter-bootstrap, event-handling, typescript-typings, svelte

Using Svelte 3.49, TypeScript, and Bootstrap 5.2, I setup an event handler for a Modal dialog (that works fine):

```html
<div on:shown.bs.modal={() => focusField.focus()} class="modal fade" id="announcementModal" aria-labelledby="announcementModalTitle">
```

...but I get a TypeScript warning for "on" in the above code...

```
(property) onshown: true
Type '{ onshown: true; }' is not assignable to type 'HTMLProps<HTMLDivElement>'.
  Property 'onshown' does not exist on type 'HTMLProps<HTMLDivElement>'.ts(2322)
Identifier expected.ts(1003)
```

Tried adding this to my global.d.ts:

```
declare namespace svelte.JSX {
  interface HTMLProps<HTMLDivElement> {
    'shown.bs.modal'?: (e: CustomEvent) => void
  }
}
```

...but it doesn't help. TypeScript seems to think the declaration should be `onshown: boolean` but that's only part of the Bootstrap Modal event name. I guess it stops at the first period. Vue.js supports quoted event names like `v-on="{ 'hide.bs.modal': handleModalClose }"`. Could not find the same for Svelte but again, the event handler works fine - only the typing is an issue.

Any thoughts on how to properly type this?

Comment: First, I believe (after brief googling) that the syntax is `show.bs.modal` not `shown`. Second, if you could replicate this issue it would be much easier to help with. Googling "svelte playground" comes up with something quite easy to use and share.

Comment: This sounds like an issue in the Svelte language processing. You might want to bring this up as an issue in [`sveltejs/language-tools`](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools).

Comment: @LaytonGB - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/modal/#events - show.bs.modal is a different event from shown.bs.modal.

Answer (score 0):

I added this:

```js
declare namespace svelte.JSX {
  interface HTMLAttributes<T> {
    'onshown.bs.modal'?: (e: CustomEvent) => void
  }
}
```

to my global.d.ts and checked "Use New Transformation" setting in VS Code -> Settings -> Extensions -> Svelte.